# POST request to Laravel

Tags: api, post, laravel-5.4, postman

My **api.php** is like below

```
Route::post('register','Api\Auth\RegisterController@register');
```

I am trying to send below `POST` request using *POSTMAN*

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register
```

But I am getting below output

```
Not allowed.
```

[image]

Comment: It says, `403 Forbidden`, I believe you haven't sent the CSRF token.

Comment: Thanks @MilanChheda. How can I send that ?

Comment: May be, this would be helpful: https://gist.github.com/ethanstenis/3cc78c1d097680ac7ef0 .. You basically need this `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` which is there in your blade templates.

Comment: Thanks @MilanChheda. But I have no blade templates. I working with API and POSTMAN. Thanks

Comment: You need to send `_token` field as a POST parameter. The value of this field should be `echo csrf_token();` OR in `VerifiyCsrfToken.php` you can specify routes that you want to exclude from csrf.

Comment: Thanks @MilanChheda. How can I get _token field Value ?